# ¿Por qué me da error "memoria insuficiente" en C# al cargar una imagen a un picture box?

Tags: c#, .net

```
    private void VentanaAdmin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // cargando la variable publica para mostrar datos
                string cmd = "Select * from Usuarios Where id_usuario="+VentanaLogin.Codigo;

                // rellenando el dataset de datos con la consulta sql

                DataSet DS = Utilidades.Ejecutar(cmd);

                txt_lbl_NomAdmin.Text = DS.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Nom_usuario"].ToString().Trim();
                txt_lbl_UsAdmin.Text = DS.Tables[0].Rows[0]["account"].ToString().Trim();
                txt_lbl_Codigo.Text = DS.Tables[0].Rows[0]["id_usuario"].ToString().Trim();


// aquí da error out of memory.
                string url_foto = DS.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Foto"].ToString().Trim();

                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(url_foto);


            }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más seguro es que la foto sea muy grande (fichero de gran tamaño) o bien **no hagas un dispose de la imagen cargada anteriormente**.

```
pictureBox.Image.Dispose(); //dispose la imagen previamente cargada.
pictureBox.Image = image;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991157/picture-box-out-of-memory

Como consejo, usa parámetros a la hora de hacer querys SQL, no concatenes cadenas para los parámetros.

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias hermano,soy nuevo en la programación y en C#, no entiendo muy bien esto "usa parámetros a la hora de hacer querys SQL, no concatenes cadenas para los parámetros." ya que la especialidad de mi area va enfocada a administrar server, pero me encanta la programación. te agradzco muchisimo haberme ayudado :)

Comment: Acabo de implementar lo que me comentaste y aun persiste el error, no es el peso pues pesan 300kb las imagenes, quizás podría ser la resolucion de las mismas?

Comment: Qué tipo de imágenes son? Jpg?

Comment: Asi es, son jpg

Comment: El error lo da justo al hacer el load from file?

Comment: Así es, como lei que no era recomendable insertar imagenes en la bd lo que hice fue insertar la url de mi imagen en mi laptop y es lo que carga esa url y despues se la asigno al picturebox, cree usted que pueda ser eso?

Comment: Es una URL o una carpeta local de tu pc.

Comment: es una carpeta local en mi pc pero la url de ubicacion en mi pc la tiene insertada la bd, de ahi la carga, añadiré una imagen para mostrarle

Comment: Es importante saber si falla a la hora de cargar la imagen o por los datos que traes de la base de datos. Pon un pantallazo del error si puedes y el número de línea.

Comment: no me deja pegar pantalla, pero al parecer ya trajo la imagen, lo cual se me hace extraño, no se pueden pegar capturas aqui en los comentarios?

Comment: Tienes que editar la pregunta. Qué tamaño (píxels) tiene la imagen?

Comment: 450x366px, la verdad no tengo idea como se arreglo

Comment: Comprueba siempre que la imagen no esté corrupta.

Comment: Gracias hermano! Saludos.